# Excel column chart with values per date

Tags: excel, charts

I have the following in Excel

```
Date    Connections
2013-10-16  6
2013-10-17  18
2013-10-18  16
2013-10-19  10
2013-10-21  9
2013-10-22  1
2013-10-23  33
2013-10-24  38
2013-10-25  15
2013-10-26  20
2013-10-27  12
2013-10-28  9
2013-10-29  7
2013-10-31  2
2013-11-01  4
2013-11-02  1
2013-11-03  1
2013-11-04  2
2013-11-05  6
2013-11-06  15
2013-11-07  11
2013-11-08  13
2013-11-09  16
2013-11-10  9
2013-11-11  20
2013-11-12  2
```

I am trying to do a column chart that shows connections per date.

Just selecting the cells and clicking chart gives

[image]

I can right click the respective axis and format to get this:

[image]

But that only shows the calue for the last date, how do I get it to show all data?
I have googled for a while now but it just seems to add to the confusion.

Comment: Select All Data and then insert the Chart.

Comment: This is what I get when selecting all data and inserting chart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this was due to faulty formatting of the date column when importing the data.
Importing the column as text and then converting it to date and everything works as expected.

Comment: also, when some rows/column are hidden, chart will display last item.